# How to store the value of a link tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If I have a url such as `<a href="JavaScript:article('40')">What is the difference between Archiving and Trashing an Article? </a>` how can I store the value of the href? Note that this is used in an ajax app so I cannot actually see this url when the user clicks it in the browser address bar. When I get the value of the href I should be able to put it in the browser and execute the same result as if the user clicks it.

Comment: What does the 'article' function do -- can you post its code? Does it return a URL?  If you put JavaScript:article('40') in your browser while on the page in question, what happens?

Comment: what it does is pull the an article from a db with the id 40. Its done with ajax so the URL doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want...

Here is howto get the href attribute and execute the javascript:

```
<a id="link" href="JavaScript:article('40')">Text</a>

eval(document.getElementById('link').href);
```

or do you want to get the number '40' and store it to the server? (Use ajax for this)

Comment: Does this mean I have to give an id to all my links? Or can I do this function after a user clicks it. How would I write a script to store the href value after the user has clicked it?

Comment: The purpose of this is to keep the function last called to use in the History API. So when the user hits back in the state obj I will have the last function called.

Comment: You should have started with this text!

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have an ID on the link - there is really no way to distinguish it from a similar `<a>` element (other than compare the contents - which I would advise against).

If you know that there is only one `<a>` element - you can get the `href` value and do with it as you please (I print it to the console, as an example):

```
var aEl = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
console.log(aEl[0].href);
```

Note that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements (or rather a `NodeList` - but let's leave it out for this purpose) and its support in Opera and Safari (IIRC) is iffy.

Alternatively (and preferably) - add an ID to your `<a>` elements if you can:

```
<a id='someID' href="JavaScript:article('40')">What is the difference between Archiving and Trashing an Article? </a>
```

and use the following to get the `href`:

```
var aEl = document.getElementById('someID');
console.log(aEl.href);
```

**EDIT**

after some thought - and in case your intent was to keep the value the `article` function returns, then you should consider takign the function invocation out of the `<a>` element and calling it during/after DOM rendering, keeping the result, but also inserting it into the `<a>` element through the same `href` attribute.

Otherwise you'd have (AFAIK) to resort to shady techniques that I don't even mention here.

Comment: The purpose of this is to keep the function last called to use in the History API. So when the user hits back in the state obj I will have the last function called.